# iOS - How to do diacritic insensitive search with SQLite.swift?

Tags: ios, search, diacritics, sqlite.swift

I'm working with SQLite.swift.
Is there any way to do an diacritic-insensitive LIKE query in SQLite? For example, this query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE "thu%"
```

would return:

```
thử
thu
thư
etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#custom-collations):

> We can create custom collating sequences by calling `createCollation` on a database connection.
>
> ```
> try db.createCollation("NODIACRITIC") { lhs, rhs in
>     return lhs.compare(rhs, options: .DiacriticInsensitiveSearch)
> }
> ```
>
> We can reference a custom collation using the `Custom` member of the `Collation` enumeration.
>
> ```
> restaurants.order(collate(.Custom("NODIACRITIC"), name))
> // SELECT * FROM "restaurants" ORDER BY "name" COLLATE "NODIACRITIC"
> ```

In your case, you could execute the following query afterwards:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name COLLATE NODIACRITIC LIKE 'thu%'
```

Comment: I've added your code and execute the query but didn't work. 
I have to put this code right after making db connection?

Comment: I've tried with other query with your syntax, but got this error: `Use of unresolved identifier 'collate'`

Comment: Do you have an example how can i get it works? Im stucking with this trouble for a day.